# Robustness check for cross-sectional data by merging data sets and creating year dummy variable

Tags: regression, statistical-significance, robust, probit

I am currently working on the effects of maternal education on child mortality with cross-sectional data. I got data sets for 2008, 2010 and 2014. I am thinking of doing a robustness checks and I received some advice and I am not sure whether it is valid or how it works on stata. I was told to merge the data sets, ie 2010 and 2014, then create a year dummy variable (i.year), then include the year dummy variable and simply run the regressions that I had for my project.

Also something I am concerned is that do the respondents have to be the same individuals? And what is the difference between running the regression separately in 2010 and 2014 and the method above?

And I actually constructed a few probit models and the significance drops as I add more controls. Is this a robustness check?

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your first question (*...do the respondents have to be the same individuals?*), it depends on your research aims. For example, if you want to analyze changes in the participants’ behaviors, attitudes, etc. over time, then you might want to measure same individuals over time.

*What is the difference between running regressions separately and the method above* [merging data and controlling for year]*?* Let's look at this toy example (don't worry if you are not familiar with `R` code). First, I am going to create two data sets (n=1000) and then merge them (actually we append data but I keep using merge for now).

```
library(fabricatr)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

# 2010 data
ID <- 1:1000
x <- rnorm(n = 1000, mean = 50, sd = 10)
y <- correlate(given = x, rho = 0.7,  draw_count, mean = 25)
year <- 0
df_2010 <- data.frame(ID, x, y, year)

# 2014 data
ID <- 1001:2000
x <- rnorm(n = 1000, mean = 80, sd = 10) # 50, 14
y <- correlate(given = x, rho = 0.7, draw_count, mean = 20)
year <- 1
df_2014 <- data.frame(ID, x, y, year)

# Merge them
df_m <- rbind(df_2010, df_2014)
```

So, I have four variables in each data set: `ID`, `x`, `y`, `year`. And I am interested in the relationship between `x` & `y`. You may think these data sets as two waves of the same cross-national survey program (e.g., ESS) for a single country. We can see differences here: mean `x` increases from 50 to 80 (see `rnorm()`), and mean `y` decreases from 25 to 20 (see `correlate`). However, `rho` (which refers to rank correlation coefficient here) remains the same. So, when I check the correlation separately between $x$ & $y$ in each data set, I can see that results are similar:

```
cor(df_2010$x, df_2010$y)
0.705932
cor(df_2014$x, df_2014$y)
0.7145714
```

What about the merged data (well I was asked to use it):

```
cor(df_m$x, df_m$y)
-0.04186663
```

Something is not right, lets check the scatterplot by year:

[image]

So, the scatterplot captures the differences (changes?) between two waves and illustrates why we have negative correlation.$^1$ Let's estimate regression models using single waves (2010 & 2014) and merged data (with and without controlling for year)

```
lmfit1 <- lm(y ~ x, df_2010)
lmfit2 <- lm(y ~ x, df_2014)
lmfit3 <- lm(y ~ x, df_m)
lmfit4 <- lm(y ~ x + year, df_m)

====================================================
                       Dependent variable:          
             ---------------------------------------
                                y                   
               (1)       (2)       (3)       (4)    
----------------------------------------------------
x            0.356*** 0.326***   -0.012    0.341*** 
             (0.011)   (0.010)   (0.007)   (0.008)  
                                                    
year                                      -15.299***
                                           (0.275)  
                                                    
Constant     7.169*** -6.186*** 23.334***  7.909*** 
             (0.578)   (0.819)   (0.450)   (0.395)  
                                                    
----------------------------------------------------
Observations  1,000     1,000     2,000     2,000   
R2            0.498     0.511     0.002     0.609   
Adjusted R2   0.498     0.510     0.001     0.609   
====================================================
Note:                  *p<0.05; **p<0.01; ***p<0.001
```

This is just a simple example, but it illustrates how you can capture the association when you adjust for `year`. And it shows you that your dummy `year` variable has a negative effect. This might not be easy to see when you run models separately in each wave. Needless to say, it gets complicated when you have multiple predictors, interactions, etc.

And your last question (adding more controls?): adding and removing regressors (as robustness checks) are common practice in some areas. My guess is that it should be done in a systematic fashion. Unfortunately, I cannot provide a satisfactory answer now, but I assume there are many studies covering this issue.

---

$^1$ And this is an example of [Simpson's Paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simpson%27s_paradox#:%7E:text=Simpson%27s%20paradox%2C%20which%20also%20goes,when%20these%20groups%20are%20combined.).

Comment: Thank you for your answer! From what I know, my robustness check is simply to see if the magnitude or signs differ across data sets or specifications. My initial aim to merge is to increase the sample size and see if the combined dataset yield -ve sign as well. Here I do not see how the year dummy is helping. Will it be approriate by simply running my regressions using lpm or the 2010 data set? I am honestly quite confused by robustness as I am aware that anything can be a robustness check and there isn't really a lot of materials to look at.

Comment: The point is to account for the systematic differences between data sets you merge (as I try to illustrate in my toy example). Dummy year helps in this respect (see models 3 & 4 in the toy example).  And I think that counts as a robustness check. It is hard to comment on any specific question (using lpm or 2010 data set) without knowing more about your analysis.

Comment: *Regarding your first question (...do the respondents have to be the same individuals?), it depends on your research aims.*---I was curious...when would you perform longitudinal analysis on different subjects? Or did I misread what you meant here?

Comment: You can't perform longitudinal analysis on different subjects. You can create pooled cross-sectional data, but that's another [topic](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/45236/what-is-the-difference-between-pooled-cross-sectional-data-and-panel-data). Why do you think that my answer somehow implies that? (I would like to edit the answer to make it clear).