# What is the difference between "repeated cross-section" and "pooled cross-section"?

Tags: repeated-measures, cross-section, pooling

What is the difference between "repeated cross-section" and "pooled cross-section"?

**Pooled cross-section** is defined e.g. [here](https://faculty.washington.edu/ezivot/econ582/introductionpaneldata.pdf) as "randomly sampled cross sections of individuals at different points in time. Example: Current population survey (CPS) in 1978 and 1988".

**Repeated cross-section** is defined e.g. [here](https://link.springer.com/referenceworkentry/10.1007/978-3-030-22009-9_578) as "one type of survey design and uses data, in which the same information is asked to an independent sample at each wave". Which is the same as the previous definition for "pooled cross-section".

[This](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/45240/154990) is an answer to a question about "pooled cross sectional data" and the answer uses the term "repeated cross sections".

So it looks like the two terms are synonymous?

Comment: Subtlety: I find that 'repeated cross-section' (aka 'cross-sectional time series'), in the political science, econometric, and other literatures often includes both (1) repetitions of cross-sectional designs (sampling & measurement), and (2) repetitions of *prospective* designs (sampling & measurement; i.e. 'cohort designs' which capture *change* during the period, e.g., annual mortality rates). These last are sometimes called 'repeated cohorts' or 'serial cohorts' designs by epidemiologists who care about differentiating inference on rates from inference on status.

Comment: robertspierre: you should "unaccept" my answer (I can't delete it while it is accepted, see the comments under it for more info). @Alexis Thanks for the comments under my answer. I still don't understand the difference Lebo & Weber make between repeated and pooled design, as apparently it's not the probability of recruitement that differ, according to what you say and the paper by Rafferty et al. (footnote 8 p. 14).

Comment: @JJJ all right......

Comment: robertspierre: sorry about that. I find things quite confusing actually, as on the surface sources seem to disagree. I put a bounty on the question to get more feedback, as I'm interested in the question too.

Comment: To add to the complexity, some sources sometimes use "pooled" to refer to panel data, e.g. see the first lines of https://www.reed.edu/economics/parker/312/notes/Notes10.pdf (HGL is short for "Hill, Griffiths, and Lim" and their 2012 book "Principles of Econometrics"). It doesn't really answer your question, but at least it shows that the meaning of the terms may vary depending on context.